# Validation vs Verification vs Evaluation

Tags: naming

While naming identifiers or function names, the terms

- **validation** (validate)
- **verification** (verify)
- **evaluation** (evaluate)

are often used synonymously.

However, there are some resources on the web defining the terms differently.

When to use which term in software projects, based on a sound definition?

Comment: Is this the good naming practice you seek: *don't use validate (validation) when you mean verify (verification) or evaluate (evaluation) and don't use verify when you mean validate or evaluate, and don't use evaluate when you mean verify or validate* ? In other words, *Use words to mean what they mean* ?  I don't really see   a question here.

Comment: There are similar questions like this one, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074384/options-settings-properties-configuration-preferences-when-and-why/2074417#2074417

I can change the question to "When to use which term"

Comment: I usualy only use evaluate when an expression is evaluated or some dynamic code is evaluated.